# Expo React Native: BarcodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync() doesnt apply a permission request

Tags: react-native, expo, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to build a Barcode scanner component and I'm using expo-barcode-scanner.
the console.log works fine and I get the ASKING text.
the dialog window doesnt show up
here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text,SafeAreaView, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';

const ScannerComponent =()=> {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const askForCameraPermission = () =>{
    console.log('ASKING')
    async () => {
                  const {status} = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
                  setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
              }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    askForCameraPermission();
    }, []);

  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
  };

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return (<View style={styles.container}><Text style={styles.text}>Requesting for camera permission</Text></View>);
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return (<View style={styles.container}><Text style={styles.text}>No access to camera</Text></View>);
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text value='hello' />
      <View style={styles.scanner}>
      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
      />
      </View>
      {scanned && <Button title={'Tap to Scan Again'} onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default ScannerComponent
```